# how to get back to imageView default src?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have an android imageView

I load a bitmap into it

and I want to remove this bitmap later on, and return the default imageView src

meaning this:

[image]

how can I set to this default image?

I have tried these unsuccessfully

```
            //mImageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            //mImageView.setImageBitmap(null);

            mImageView.setImageResource(0);
```

Comment: Look in your layout xml file. There is AFAIK no default unless you specify one.

Comment: I want to use the Android default from above

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom view which extends the ImageView and keep the original image. When you want to return to the default you simply change it since you know the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this:

`mImageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);`

[image]